# d3: collapsible treee by mbostock - how to add new paths?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Please see
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

I want to add code so that when the user presses mouse down on one node and releases mouseup on another, it should draw a curved link from the first node to the second. I have added code to handle mousedown and mouseup events on nodes and storing mousedown_node and mouseup_node. 
But I do not know how to do the following:-

1. What code to write to draw link?
2. How to make sure that the link is curved so that it does not cut any other node in between. (it is ok if it cuts other links). As an example, suppose the user drags from analytics to data. If the link is straight, then it will cut animate in between. That is why I want curved links. Any curved link is fine so long it does not cut any other node in between.
3. How to put arrow head at the end of the link?

I saw some other examples in which links are added. But somehow I am not able to do so in this sample.
Thank you.

Comment: [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347) should help.

Comment: That example is for force layout. Can I use the same in tree layout too?

Comment: Yes. This is not specific to the force layout.